# How to run a mysql stored procedure in django with two output parameters when data is received through REST API?

Tags: python, mysql, django, stored-procedures

I am working on a django project where I have to use a stored procedure to update multiple tables and it gives two output parameters. There are four input parameters which comes from REST api.

The procedure runs properly in phpmyadmin/MySql.

In a pure python script it doesn't update the required tables but gives the output properly.

In django I am not able to run the procedure.

I just want to know how to set the output parameters properly and execute the procedure in django.

I have tried it in a seperate python script but it only gives the output parameters and doesn't update the tables. In djando I tried to edit the views.py.

pure python script:

```
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import Error
from mysql.connector import errorcode

var1 = " "
var2 = " "

try:
    mySQL_conn = mysql.connector.connect(host='192.111.11.111',
                                   database='Safemode',
                                   user='root',
                                   password='password here')
    cursor = mySQL_conn.cursor()
    x = cursor.callproc('ProcessIOTData',[1,2,"3","2019-06- 
                                           21T11:56:33Z",var1,var2])

    for result in cursor.stored_results():
        print(result.fetchall())

    for output in x:
    print(x)

except mysql.connector.Error as error:
    print("Failed to execute stored procedure: {}".format(error))
finally:

    if (mySQL_conn.is_connected()):
        cursor.close()
        mySQL_conn.close()
        print("connection is closed")
```

IN Django(views.py). I have also not saved the data from the api as that will also be done the procedure:

```
.
.
.
from django.db import connection


class IotTrackerListView(viewsets.ViewSet):
.
.
.
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    serializer = IotTrackerSerializer(data=request.data)

    var1=" "
    var2=" "


    cur = connection.cursor()  
    x=cur.callproc('ProcessIOTData', [request.data['iotiid'],request.data['sensortype'],request.data['sensordata'],request.data['trackingtime'],var1,var2]) 

    cur.execute('ProcessIOTData')
    result.fetchall()
    for incident in x:
        print(incident)
    cur.close()

    if serializer.is_valid():
        ##### serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data, 
                                     status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    return Response(serializer.errors,
                                 status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Procedure :

```
ProcessIOTData`(In pIOTIID Int(15),
In pSensorType Int(1),
In pSensorData VarChar(25),
IN pIncidentTime DateTime,
Out pStatus Int(1),
Out pIncidentIID Int(15))
```

API parameters:

```
{
        "iottrackiid": 9,
        "iotiid": 1,
        "trackingtime": "2019-06-21T11:56:31Z",
        "sensortype": 5,
        "sensordata": "0"
 }
```

In django no error occurs without any type of output when a new set of data is posted via the api.